# SceneKit: how to tell SCNNode that geometry shader modifier performed transformations?

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, transformation, cg

My question is related to `SceneKit` framework.

I have a geometry shader modifier that does some deformation that involves rotation of the whole geometry. In my specific case it is important to deform and then rotate a vertex inside the shader. Everything works great. After finishing the deformation I cannot interact with this node, since now it is located in a different orientation and position - the geometry was deformed and flipped. As I understand, I need to tell the host node that geometry was updated by shader.

My question is: `How to sync transformation changes between geometry shader modifier and Scene Graph - the transformation matrix of host SCNNode instance?`

Comment: what do you mean by "I cannot interact with this node"? What are you trying to do that's not working?

Comment: By interaction issue I mean that I cannot perform hit test with the node that was modified by geometry shader modifier. Hit test cannot be performed because geometry is in one location (after applying vertex transformation), but host SCNNode is not aware of that - the host node still in the same position.

Comment: What I do is:

1. I apply geometry transformation that eventually rotates plane
2. After that I try to interact with that node by simple hit testing
3. However it is not possible because geometry is in one location but host SCNNode remans in the original location

Comment: Shader modifiers are executed at every frame on the GPU. Hit-testing in done on the CPU using the original vertex positions. There's no API to update the CPU geometry from the GPU geometry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for enlightening! Is there any way to sync geometries between CPU and GPU? Maybe tell SCNNode somehow that geometry was changed?

Comment: By "any way" I mean "trick" that may not be the most efficient from performance point of view.

Comment: No you can't. You would have to mutate the position geometry source yourself using the same modifier, and then create a new geometry. But that's *highly* inefficient.

Comment: You really helped me. Thanks a lot!